# Mybatis: How can I get the first element from the passed parameter?

Tags: sql, mybatis

Given that my parameterType is an ArrayList, is it possible to get the first element from that list and use it  in the where clause ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="db">

    <select id="selectFlag" resultType="java.lang.Boolean" parameterType="java.util.ArrayList">
        select TOP 1 'true' from customers where id = ???
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Answer (score 8):

If your query uses one id, why are you sending a list and then picking the first one for the query?

Change your `parameterType` to an `int` (or whatever type the id has), don't send a list. This is a simple approach that also conveys the information that you are only retrieving data based on a single id. Your condition then changes to something like:

```
where id = #{id}
```

If you must absolutely send an `ArrayList` (for whatever reason) then MyBatis supports OGNL expressions so something like this should work:

```
where id = #{list[0]}
```

Unfortunately MyBatis lacks on the documentation side, so you can find out about things like this only by looking at the source code.